# What's the use of the record type in C# (in ASP.NET Core MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Recently I discovered a third type of object in C#: the `record`; actually 2: the `record struct` and the `record class`. As I understand the type does not differ significantly from normal classes (I never used `structs` in my programs). The big advantage seems to me that they are easier to construct, because of their constructor+property-in-1 syntax. Is this a correct point of view? I would like to use them then for building my View Models in the ASP.NET Core MVC framework. I don't know why they just added the syntax to classes? The doubt that I miss something holds me back from using them.

Comment: "*I never used structs in my programs*". Sure you did, all numbers are structures.

Comment: No, I never use numbers in my programs ;^)